# Regex Match all characters between text and symbols

Tags: regex, match

**EXAMPLE:** CODE: 123456 / NUMBER: AA1234567890

I want to extract the *CODE* with one RegEX and the *NUMBER* with another. I started with the first one and tried:

```
(?<=CODE:)(.*)(?=/)
```

The idea is to *TRIM* the matches afterwards, however, the RegEx above does not work. I cannot figure out why.

**NB**: Both the *CODE* & *NUMBER* may contain numbers and text, but not special characters neither symbols. The length of each match is always the same like in the example.

Comment: you have to escape the forward slash. To fix spaces `(?<=CODE:) ?(\S*) ?(?=\/)`

Comment: Just keep it simple and use multiple capture groups. i.e. `CODE: ([a-zA-Z0-9]+) / NUMBER: ([a-zA-Z0-9]+)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following with `/` used as separator:

`(?:NUMBER|CODE):\s([^\s^\/.]*)`

Captures `123456` and `AA1234567890` for your example provided.

Answer (score 1):

Use a capture group (parentheses) to get each part.

```
CODE:\s{1}(\d+) \/ NUMBER:\s{1}([A-Z,1-9]+)
```

The first capture group gives you the code and the second the number.

Here is a working example:  [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/BivK6T/1)